# How to make the floating label stay after textbox is fillled?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying out floating labels in textbox using css but once the text is typed and the focus is removed from the textbox, the label comes down hiding the content of the textbox. I did this using a YouTube tutorial and I can't figure out where I've made a mistake. I need help with keeping the label up please.

```css
        .main{
            font-size:15px;
            position:relative;
            left:20%;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        .textbox{
            height:30px;
            width:100%;
            color: grey;
            padding-top:20px;
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }

        .label-name{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0px;
            top:0px;
            padding:0px 2px 0px 2px;
            height:30px;
            width:100%;
            pointer-events:none;
        }

        .label-name::after{
            content:"";
            position: absolute;
            left:0px;
            bottom:-23px;
            height:30px;
            width:100%;
            border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        }

       

        .span-name{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:-15px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

         .span-name::after{
            position: absolute;
            content:"";
            bottom:-23px;
        }

        .textbox:focus + .label-name .span-name {
            transform: translateY(-150%);
            font-size: 13px;
            color: #5fa8d3;
        }

        .textbox:focus, .textbox:valid{
            box-shadow:none;
            outline:none;
        }
        

        .textbox:focus + .label-name::after,
        .textbox:valid + .label-name .span-name::after {
            transform:translateY(0%);
        }
```

```html
<div class="main">
            <input class="textbox" type="text"/>
            <label class="label-name">
                <span class="span-name">Name</span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify two things in the code to get this working:

- Add `required` to the input so that the `:valid` psuedo-selector is updated based on the value provided as the input
- Add `transform: translateY(-150%)` property to the selector `.textbox:valid + .label-name .span-name`.

Working example:

```css
        .main{
            font-size:15px;
            position:relative;
            left:20%;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        .textbox{
            height:30px;
            width:100%;
            color: grey;
            padding-top:20px;
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }

        .label-name{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0px;
            top:0px;
            padding:0px 2px 0px 2px;
            height:30px;
            width:100%;
            pointer-events:none;
        }

        .label-name::after{
            content:"";
            position: absolute;
            left:0px;
            bottom:-23px;
            height:30px;
            width:100%;
            border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        }

       

        .span-name{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:-15px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

         .span-name::after{
            position: absolute;
            content:"";
            bottom:-23px;
        }

        .textbox:focus + .label-name .span-name,
        .textbox:valid + .label-name .span-name  { /* add new selector here */
            transform: translateY(-150%);
            font-size: 13px;
            color: #5fa8d3;
        }

        .textbox:focus, .textbox:valid{
            box-shadow:none;
            outline:none;
        }
        

        .textbox:focus + .label-name::after,
        .textbox:valid + .label-name .span-name::after {
            transform:translateY(0%);
        }
```

```html
<div class="main">
            <input class="textbox" type="text" required/>
            <label class="label-name">
                <span class="span-name">Name</span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.group input {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    border: none;
}
.group input:read-only ~ label  {
    top: -12px !important;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.group input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.group label {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 8px;
    top: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
.group input:focus~label,
input:valid~label {
    top: -12px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.group .bar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.group .bar:before {
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    background-color:black;
    left:0;
    right:0
}
```

```html
<div class="group w_100">
         <input
             type="text" 
             id="email" 
             name="email" required/>
             <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
             <label class="left_0px" htmlFor="email">Email</label>
    </div>
```